# Longest Increasing Sub sequence

Tags: algorithm, lis

Here is the pseudo code for longest increasing sub sequence given on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)

```
L = 0
 for i = 1, 2, ... n:
    binary search for the largest positive j ≤ L
    such that X[M[j]] < X[i] (or set j = 0 if no such value exists)
    P[i] = M[j]
    if j == L or X[i] < X[M[j+1]]:
       M[j+1] = i
       L = max(L, j+1)
```

I have understood how the code works. The only thing i cannot understand is the necessity of this statement (if j == L or X[i] < X[M[j+1]]:)
I have tried running the algorithm on many examples and what i could make out is that in all the cases either j == L or X[i] < X[M[j+1]] and so the if statement always evaluates to True. Could you give me an example where the if loop is false and thus required for the algorithm ??

Comment: Would my answer here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472723/absurd-condition-in-longest-increasing-subquence/17483178#17483178

Comment: not really .... i was looking for an nlogn solution ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there are duplicates the `if` condition will fail

Consider `X={2, 2, 2}`

`if` Condition fails when `j=0` and `L=1`